# Using pexpect to automate a manage.py syncdb dialogue

Tags: python, expect, pexpect

I am trying to use pexpect to automate this dialogue.  Also below is the python program using pexpect.  When I run the code...it waits for input at "Would you like to create one now? (yes/no):" then timesout with an error.  It is expecting a yes or no.  So...where did I err?  The string matches the first input?

```
ubuntu@ip-10-142-73-169:/opt/graphite/webapp/graphite$ sudo python manage.py syncdb
Creating tables ...
Creating table account_profile
Creating table account_variable
Creating table account_view
Creating table account_window
Creating table account_mygraph
Creating table dashboard_dashboard_owners
Creating table dashboard_dashboard
Creating table events_event
Creating table auth_permission
Creating table auth_group_permissions
Creating table auth_group
Creating table auth_user_user_permissions
Creating table auth_user_groups
Creating table auth_user
Creating table auth_message
Creating table django_session
Creating table django_admin_log
Creating table django_content_type
Creating table tagging_tag
Creating table tagging_taggeditem

You just installed Django's auth system, which means you don't have any superusers defined.
Would you like to create one now? (yes/no): 
Username (Leave blank to use 'root'): 
E-mail address: 
Password: 
Password (again):
```

Python script:

```
import pexpect
child = pexpect.spawn ('python /opt/graphite/webapp/graphite/manage.py syncdb')
child.expect ('Would you like to create one now? (yes/no):')
child.sendline ('yes')
child.expect ("""Username (Leave blank to use 'root'):""")
child.sendline ('admin')
child.expect ("E-mail address:")
child.sendline ('david@gmail.com')
child.expect ('Password:')
child.sendline ('test')
child.expect ('Password (again):')
child.sendline ('test')





Creating tables ...
Creating table account_profile
Creating table account_variable
Creating table account_view
Creating table account_window
Creating table account_mygraph
Creating table dashboard_dashboard_owners
Creating table dashboard_dashboard
Creating table events_event
Creating table auth_permission
Creating table auth_group_permissions
Creating table auth_group
Creating table auth_user_user_permissions
Creating table auth_user_groups
Creating table auth_user
Creating table auth_message
Creating table django_session
Creating table django_admin_log
Creating table django_content_type
Creating table tagging_tag
Creating table tagging_taggeditem

You just installed Django's auth system, which means you don't have any superusers defined.
Would you like to create one now? (yes/no): Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 5, in <module>
    child.expect ('Would you like to create one now? (yes/no):')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pexpect.py", line 1311, in expect
    return self.expect_list(compiled_pattern_list, timeout, searchwindowsize)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pexpect.py", line 1325, in expect_list
    return self.expect_loop(searcher_re(pattern_list), timeout, searchwindowsize)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pexpect.py", line 1409, in expect_loop
    raise TIMEOUT (str(e) + '\n' + str(self))
pexpect.TIMEOUT: Timeout exceeded in read_nonblocking().
<pexpect.spawn object at 0x7ffb875847d0>
version: 2.3 ($Revision: 399 $)
command: /usr/bin/python
args: ['/usr/bin/python', 'manage.py', 'syncdb']
searcher: searcher_re:
    0: re.compile("Would you like to create one now? (yes/no):")
buffer (last 100 chars): em, which means you don't have any superusers defined.
Would you like to create one now? (yes/no): 
before (last 100 chars): em, which means you don't have any superusers defined.
Would you like to create one now? (yes/no): 
after: <class 'pexpect.TIMEOUT'>
match: None
match_index: None
exitstatus: None
flag_eof: False
pid: 12938
child_fd: 3
closed: False
timeout: 30
delimiter: <class 'pexpect.EOF'>
logfile: <open file '<stdout>', mode 'w' at 0x7ffb876c51e0>
logfile_read: None
logfile_send: None
maxread: 2000
ignorecase: False
searchwindowsize: None
delaybeforesend: 0.05
delayafterclose: 0.1
delayafterterminate: 0.1
```

Comment: specify the `timeout=300` in pexpect.spawn call itself if the process takes a long time, also check and show child.before/child.after output

Comment: Hi..I added the traceback.  In times out at 30 seconds.  THe proccess does not tack that long.  It hangs on the first input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe [pexpect](http://www.noah.org/wiki/pexpect#Overview) uses regular expression syntax.

```
child.expect ('Would you like to create one now.*?:')
```

I'm guessing the above would work fine.
You could alternatively escape the '?' and possibly the brackets to get better results also.

```
child.expect ('Would you like to create one now\? \(yes\/no\):')
```

Comment: There's also an `expect_exact` method which matches regular strings.

Answer (score 1):

The regular expression syntax was tripping me up for a while as well. Here's the automation code that worked for me:

```
p = pexpect.spawn("python manage.py syncdb")
p.logfile = sys.stdout 
p.expect(r"Would you like to create one now\? \(yes\/no\): ")
p.sendline("yes")
p.expect(r"Username \(leave blank to use '.*'\): ")
p.sendline("admin")
p.expect(r"Email address: ")
p.sendline("admin@admin.com")
p.expect(r"Password: ")
p.sendline("admin")
p.expect(r"Password \(again\): ")
p.sendline("admin")
```