# How can automate autoanswer my python script?

Tags: python, bash, automation

I have an installation script which would ask me some question.

or can I solve this [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10191113/using-pexpect-to-automate-a-manage-py-syncdb-dialogue) without using pexpect?

In my django project

```
python manage.py syncdb

....
....
....
Would you like to create a default user (yes/no)?
What is the username?
What is the password?
....
....
```

I want to automate this process by typing yes , root and 12345.

Can I do it automatically?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes... but you *should* do it by passing the option to bypass superuser creation and supplying a fixture instead.

Comment: But how can i acheive that without changing the python script code?

Comment: Options are passed in the shell. Fixtures are loaded via the shell. How would Python be involved?

Comment: do u mind illustrate this by an simple example? not familiar fixutres and options...

Comment: `./manage.py help syncdb` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/

Comment: but how can I know what model, and field i need to create?

Comment: Do it once, then export the fixture.

Comment: Do you mind telling me the step in more detail? I would be grateful if you can provide more information...